# finding multiple different paths of unknown width

Tags: algorithm

I have no problem with normal pathfinding, but the task I'm currently working on requires me to find all unique paths in a grid, where each path can be several nodes wide. For example:

```
A#######################B
 #######################
 #######################
 #####             #####
 #####             #####
 #######################
 #######################
```

Where # is a traversable node. In the example above it's easy to observe that there are exactly 2 unique paths form A to B. We could reduce it to something like this:

```
A#######################B
 #                     #
 #                     #
 #######################
```

But the computer does not understand the concept of 'uniqueness' and it will chart out every path from A to B, not only the ones that are unique.How do I go about this?

Comment: How do you define a unique path?

Comment: `"the computer does not understand the concept of 'uniqueness'"` - Computers (minus AI*) don't understand things, they do what you tell them. I suspect you're talking about some specific path generation algorithm not working as desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to [skeletonize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_skeleton) the input.

Skeletonization (or building a topological skeleton) of a given shape is the operation specifically designed to preserve connectivity while discarding path width.